# Why entrypoint is set to 'bin/true' in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is the `docker-compose.yml` file in MEAN.js. Could anyone can explain why the `entrypoint` is set to `/bin/true` for web-data and db-data? Is this necessary? and what would happen if I remove it? Many thanks.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    container_name: meanjs
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
     - "5858:5858"
     - "8080:8080"
     - "35729:35729"
    environment:
     - NODE_ENV=development
     - DB_1_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR=db
    depends_on:
     - db
    volumes_from:
     - web-data
  web-data:
    build: .
    entrypoint: /bin/true
    volumes:
     - ./:/opt/mean.js
     - /opt/mean.js/node_modules
     - /opt/mean.js/public
     - /opt/mean.js/uploads
  db:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    volumes_from:
      - db-data
  db-data:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /var/lib/mongodb
      - /var/log/mongodb
    entrypoint: /bin/true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an older version of Docker-compose. The reason for doing this is to start a container, which creates volumes and then exits.

So the below starts a container and exists

```
  db-data:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /var/lib/mongodb
      - /var/log/mongodb
    entrypoint: /bin/true
```

Inside that container these volumes path get created.

```
      - /data/db
      - /var/lib/mongodb
      - /var/log/mongodb
```

Then mongo uses `volumes_from` to store data in this container

```
  db:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    volumes_from:
      - db-data
```

`volumes_from` is no deprecated in Compose 3.X and should not be used. Instead either you should use named of anonymous volumes.

So the compose would change to something like below

**Anonymous volumes**

```
version: '3.3'
....
  db:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - /data/db
      - /var/lib/mongodb
      - /var/log/mongodb
```

**Named volumes**

```
version: '3.3'
....
  db:
    image: mongo:3.2
    restart: always
    ports:
     - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodata:/data/db
      - mongodata:/var/lib/mongodb
      - mongodata:/var/log/mongodb
volumes:
  mongodata: {}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tarun Lalwani, but I see version 2 also support volumes method you mentioned in version 3 examples, why it not used this direct way as version 3?

Comment: Because both features are valid. It's a matter of choice. But there are times when `volumes_from` is much helpful. Like in on case we used to have a app container with host mapped volumes. We would run another container using `volumes_from` from this container, do some build and it will automatically places our files in the other container. This helped us avoid 14-15 mount entries to be duplicated on both sides. Not version '3' doesn't allow that. So based on your thought process and approach you would have used `volumes` or `volumes_from`

Comment: Tarun, thank you for the detailed explanation, it's very helpful.

Comment: @PageNotFound if you think an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark under the answers score. That way other people know the issue has been resolved. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for some more info on it.